# Geometry problem I am having trouble to solve

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, power-of-the-point

> Prove that $AC = \sqrt{ab}$
>
> [image]
>
> $a$ is $AB$; $b$ is $CD$; the dot is the origin of the circle. ABCD is a trapezoid, meaning AB || DC.

My attempt at solving:

According to this rule,

[image]

$$MA^2 = MB \cdot MC$$

I can apply this rule and say that $DA^2 = b\cdot DE$. If I manage to prove that $DE = a$, I solve the problem, because if $DE = a$, that means that $DA = BE$, which leads to $BE = AC$, because both are diagonal of the equilateral trapezoid (ABCE) in the circle.

Comment: Do we know that $\overline{AB}\parallel\overline{CD}$?

Comment: HINT: triangles $ABC$ and $CAD$ are similar.

Comment: You don't have enough information. 1) you can move the point $B$ about and thus change $a$ but keep $AC$ and $b$ the same so $\sqrt{ab}$ can be changed to many values but $AC$ will stay what it is.  2) Is the circle a unit circle?

Comment: we do know that AB ∥ CD. ABCD is a trapezoid, my bad didn't mention it, it's quite essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be on a ray $DA$ beyond $A$

- $\angle CDA = \angle BAX = \angle ACB$ (tangent-chord)
- $\angle DAC = \angle ABC$ (tangent-chord)

So triangles $\Delta ADC$ and $\Delta BCA$ are similar, so: $${AC\over AB} = {DC\over AC}\implies AC^2 = AB\cdot DC$$

and thus a conclusion.